# Workbench fails to connect when using SSH tunnel to hosted DB

Tags: database-connection, mysql-workbench, ssh-keys

experiencing connecting workbench through SSH tunnel to connect to a hosted mysql DB.  I'm using port 3309 as I have a local wamp server running mysql on 33066
My first time trying to connect via SSH so any help would be appreciated...

If I try through workbench using standard TCP/IP over SSH I get the below error message

Failed to Connect to MySQL at dbxxx.db.1and1.com:3306 through SSH tunnel at user@homexxxxxxx.1and1-data.host:22 with user dboxxxxxx

[Content]
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

If I use an SSH connection via putty with port forwarding I get the following error

Putty port forward config: source = 3309 destination = dbxxx.db.1and1.com:3306

Error I get back when connecting through workbench is:
Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3309 with user dbuser

[Content]
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: No I didn't.  My web host is Ionos/1and1 and they seem to have totally blocked any type of connection other than PHP My Admin